# Sublime running Ruby code can't open a spreadsheet

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, spreadsheet

My Code:

```
require 'spreadsheet'

Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet.open "SearchData1.xls"
puts book
```

I tried running this in Sublime but I got this error:

```
 could not locate a workbook, possibly an empty file passed (RuntimeError)
```

Running the same file through the command line executes the program correctly with no errors. Can anybody help me figure out why Sublime can't run this code?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The file was on a network drive which can causes us problems with directory paths. I didn't think of it since the spreadsheet was in the same folder, but moving it to a directory on my C: drive fixed it.

Comment: Ah sorry, turned my comment into an answer before i saw your comment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of running `puts Dir.pwd` from Sublime and `pwd` from the command line. Probably you are operating on different directories. You may also try specifying an absolute path.